# Report groups correctly but shows wrong header

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I am writing an SSRS report that will group on data depending on if the user passes a customer number or a project number. The report groups the values correctly, but the grouping header shows the opposite of what it's grouping on.

For the example below I have called the report passing in a custnumstart value. It is grouping on customer number but the column that is showing the grouping is the project number.

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!CustNumStart.Value) 
AND (Parameters!ShowDetails.Value = 0), Fields!Proj_Num.Value,
 IIF((IsNothing(Parameters!ProjectStart.Value) 
  AND Parameters!ShowDetails.Value = 0), Fields!Cust_Num.Value, ""))
```

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `ShowDetails`?

Comment: It's 0. So I want it to group by project number if the customer number is empty and they don't check show details (sent as 0).

Comment: So at run time what is the value of `CustNumStart` parameter?

Comment: It's null, I'm calling the report by ProjectStart

Comment: So the statement is correct.

Comment: Sorry, for that example customer number isn't null, it has a value. It's grouping by customer, but the header is showing project number, not customer number.

Comment: Just for grins... replace `IsNothing(Parameters!CustNumStart.Value)` with `Parameters!CustNumStart.Value = ""` and see what you get.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out, it was in the text box value expression, not in the group expression. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by correcting the text box value (Text box properties -> Value) to be:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!CustNumStart.Value) AND Parameters!ShowDetails.Value = 0, Fields!Proj_Num.Value, Fields!Cust_Num.Value))
```

not changing the way the report was grouping